# Passing variables to :label by reference in batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to write a simple batch script, that automates pulling and pushing from and to github repo. There is a `:check_file` **label**, where I check if the file *exists* and it is not *empty*.

I have problems with passing `EXE_PATH_OBTAINED` and  `GIT_PATH_OBTAINED` by reference. Those are flags, that indicate, if the script managed to get the paths needed.

Here is the code snippet:

```
@echo off

set AUTOGIT_DIR=%USERPROFILE%\autogit
set FILE_EXE_PATH=%AUTOGIT_DIR%\exe_path.txt
set FILE_GIT_PATH=%AUTOGIT_DIR%\git_path.txt

set EXE_PATH_OBTAINED=-1
set GIT_PATH_OBTAINED=-1

:prompt
call :check_folder %AUTOGIT_DIR%
call :check_file %FILE_EXE_PATH% %EXE_PATH_OBTAINED%
call :check_file %FILE_GIT_PATH% %GIT_PATH_OBTAINED%

:check_folder
if not exist %1\ (
    mkdir %1
)
exit /b

:check_file
if exist %1 (
    set %2=0
    for %%i in (%1) do (
        if %%~zi gtr 0 set %2=1
    )
) else (
    set %2=-1
exit /b
```

I am quite new to scripting.

Comment: DoubleQuote your variables when calling ie: `Call "%variablename%"` in your function, use the tilde modifier `~` to remove DoubleQuote where needed. Ie `Echo(%~1`

Comment: It worked for me, when I simply put `var _name` without anything and when referenced to it as you said - with `~`.

Comment: It is best practice to use QUOTATION MARK characters in the `SET` command. `set "AUTOGIT_DIR=%USERPROFILE%\autogit"`. Also, path variables should always use QUOTATION MARK characters. `"%FILE_EXE_PATH%"`

Comment: @lit, why should I use them? What do they do?

Comment: @tokechu, please try each of these commands and report the results. `DIR C:\Program Files` and `DIR "C:\Program Files"`

Comment: @lit, the 1st one told me the name of the `C:` drive, its serial number, and 2 errors `File not found`. The 2nd one listed the directories and files in it.

Comment: I mean, it is clear to me, that the command without quotes does not work properly, because the cmd perceives `C:\Program` and `Files` as 2 separate strings, but I still don't understand what it has to do with variables.